# Python 3.5 и pyqt 5.1

Tags: python, pyqt

Будет ли работать Python 3.5 и pyqt 5.1?

В установщике pyqt написано, что он для Python 3.4, а я скачал последнюю версию.

Comment: предлагаю попробовать

Answer (score 3):

Да, будет. Новые версии всегда поддерживают старые библиотеки (Python 2.7 и Python 3 не в счёт, они как два разных языка)